# How to refer to something as an object instead of as a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, multidimensional-array, game-engine

Let's say I have two objects of the MapTile class:

```
class MapTile(object):                       #The main class for stationary things that inhabit the grid ... grass, trees, rocks and stuff.
        def __init__(self, name, internal_column, internal_row, visible):
            self.name = name
            self.internal_column = internal_column
            self.internal_row = internal_row
            self.visible = visible
```

Which inhabit a 2-dimensional array, their respective internal_column and internal_row attributes representing their coordinates in the array.

I want to write a function that returns the distance between two such objects. Here is what I have so far:

```
def return_distance(self, pointA, pointB):
        distance = math.sqrt((pointA.internal_column - pointB.internal_column)**2 + (pointA.internal_row - pointB.internal_row)**2)
        return distance
```

Where pointA and pointB would be the two objects.

When I try it out, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kosay.jabre/Desktop/Monster.py", line 380, in <module>
    Map.update()
  File "/Users/kosay.jabre/Desktop/Monster.py", line 297, in update
    if Map.return_distance(Map.Grid[column][row], character) <= character.visionrange:
  File "/Users/kosay.jabre/Desktop/Monster.py", line 245, in return_distance
    distance = math.sqrt((pointA.internal_column - pointB.internal_column)**2 + (pointA.internal_row - pointB.internal_row)**2)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'internal_column'
```

I am calling the distance function like this:

```
for character in Map.everyone:
    for column in range(MAPSIZE):
        for row in range(MAPSIZE):
            if Map.return_distance(Map.Grid[column][row], character) <= character.visionrange:
                Map.Grid[column][row].visible = True
```

What should I do? How can I access the attributes of the object in "Map.Grid[column][row]" instead of "Map.Grid[column][row]" itself as a list? Here is how Map.Grid is created:

```
MAPSIZE = 25

class Map(object):              #The main class; where the action happens
    global MAPSIZE
    Grid = []
    friendlies = []
    enemies = []
    everyone = [friendlies + enemies]
    visible = []

    for row in range(MAPSIZE):     # Creating grid
        Grid.append([])
        for column in range(MAPSIZE):
            Grid[row].append([])

    for row in range(MAPSIZE):     #Filling grid with grass
        for column in range(MAPSIZE):
            TempTile = MapTile("Grass", column, row, False)
            Grid[column][row].append(TempTile)
```

And I add things directly to Map.everyone like this:

```
for column in range(MAPSIZE):
            for row in range(MAPSIZE):
                for i in range(len(Map.Grid[column][row])):
                    if Map.Grid[column][row][i].__class__.__name__ == "Character":
                        Map.everyone.append(Map.Grid[column][row][i])
```

Here is the full, full code as I'm running it:

```
import random
import math
import pygame

pygame.init()                                 
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()                   
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode([650, 650])  
DONE = False                                  
MAPSIZE = 25   #how many tiles
TURN = 0


TILEWIDTH  = 20    #pixel size of tile                               
TILEHEIGHT = 20
TILEMARGIN = 4

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)                             
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
BROWN = (123, 123, 0)
MOVECOLOR = (150, 250, 150)

KeyLookup = {
    pygame.K_LEFT: "W",
    pygame.K_RIGHT: "E",
    pygame.K_DOWN: "S",
    pygame.K_UP: "N"
}

class MapTile(object):                       #The main class for stationary things that inhabit the grid ... grass, trees, rocks and stuff.
    def __init__(self, name, internal_column, internal_row, visible):
        self.name = name
        self.internal_column = internal_column
        self.internal_row = internal_row
        self.visible = visible

class Character(object):                    #can move around and do cool stuff
    def __init__(self, name, HP, internal_column, internal_row, damage, allegiance):
        self.name = name
        self.HP = HP
        self.internal_column = internal_column
        self.internal_row = internal_row
        self.damage = damage
        self.allegiance = allegiance

    visionrange = 10
    moves_left = 15
    direction = "N"

    def move(self, direction):      #how characters move around
        if self.collision_check(direction):
            print("Collision")
            return
        if self.moves_left == 0:
            print("No more moves left")
            return

        elif direction == "N":                    
                self.internal_row -= 1
                self.direction = "N"
        elif direction == "W":
                self.internal_column -= 1
                self.direction = "W"
        elif direction == "E":
                self.internal_column += 1
                self.direction = "E"
        elif direction == "S":
                self.internal_row += 1
                self.direction = "S"

        self.moves_left = self.moves_left - 1


    def collision_check(self, direction):       
        if direction == "N":
            if self.internal_row == 0:
                return True
            if len(Map.Grid[self.internal_column][(self.internal_row)-1]) > 1:
                return True
        elif direction == "W":
            if self.internal_column == 0:
                return True
            if len(Map.Grid[self.internal_column-1][(self.internal_row)]) > 1:
                return True
        elif direction == "E":
            if self.internal_column == MAPSIZE-1:
                return True
            if len(Map.Grid[self.internal_column+1][(self.internal_row)]) > 1:
                return True
        elif direction == "S":
            if self.internal_row == MAPSIZE-1:
                return True
            if len(Map.Grid[self.internal_column][(self.internal_row)+1]) > 1:
                return True

        return False

    def attack(self, direction):
        if self.collision_check(direction):
            print("Attack attempt.")
            if self.direction == "N":
              for i in range(0, len(Map.Grid[self.internal_column][self.internal_row-1])):
                if Map.Grid[int(self.internal_column)][int(self.internal_row-1)][i].__class__.__name__ == "Character":
                    Map.Grid[self.internal_column][self.internal_row-1][i].HP -= self.damage
                    print(str(self.damage) + " damage")
            elif self.direction == "E":
                for i in range(0, len(Map.Grid[self.internal_column+1][self.internal_row])):
                    if Map.Grid[self.internal_column+1][self.internal_row][i].__class__.__name__ == "Character":
                        Map.Grid[self.internal_column+1][self.internal_row][i].HP -= self.damage
                        print(str(self.damage) + " damage")
            elif self.direction == "W":
                for i in range(0, len(Map.Grid[self.internal_column-1][self.internal_row])):
                    if Map.Grid[self.internal_column-1][self.internal_row][i].__class__.__name__ == "Character":
                        Map.Grid[self.internal_column-1][self.internal_row][i].HP -= self.damage
                        print(str(self.damage) + " damage")
            elif self.direction == "S":
                for i in range(0, len(Map.Grid[self.internal_column][self.internal_row+1])):
                    if Map.Grid[self.internal_column][self.internal_row+1][i].__class__.__name__ == "Character":
                        Map.Grid[self.internal_column][self.internal_row+1][i].HP -= self.damage
                        print(str(self.damage) + " damage")

            self.moves_left = self.moves_left - 1

    def ranged_attack(self, direction):
            if self.direction == "S":
                for k in range(1, (MAPSIZE - self.internal_row)):
                    for i in range(0, len(Map.Grid[self.internal_column][self.internal_row + k])):
                        if Map.Grid[self.internal_column][self.internal_row + k][i].__class__.__name__ == "Character":
                            Map.Grid[self.internal_column][self.internal_row + k][i].HP -= self.damage
                            print(str(self.damage) + " damage")
                            self.moves_left = self.moves_left - 1 
            if self.direction == "N":
                for k in range(1, self.internal_row):
                    for i in range(0, len(Map.Grid[self.internal_column][self.internal_row - k])):
                        if Map.Grid[self.internal_column][self.internal_row - k][i].__class__.__name__ == "Character":
                            Map.Grid[self.internal_column][self.internal_row - k][i].HP -= self.damage
                            print(str(self.damage) + " damage")
                            self.moves_left = self.moves_left - 1
            if self.direction == "W":
                for k in range(1, self.internal_column):
                    for i in range(0, len(Map.Grid[self.internal_column - k][self.internal_row])):
                        if Map.Grid[self.internal_column - k][self.internal_row][i].__class__.__name__ == "Character":
                            Map.Grid[self.internal_column - k][self.internal_row][i].HP -= self.damage
                            print(str(self.damage) + " damage")
                            self.moves_left = self.moves_left - 1
            if self.direction == "E":
                for k in range(1, (MAPSIZE - self.internal_column)):
                    for i in range(0, len(Map.Grid[self.internal_column + k][self.internal_row])):
                        if Map.Grid[self.internal_column + k][self.internal_row][i].__class__.__name__ == "Character":
                            Map.Grid[self.internal_column + k][self.internal_row][i].HP -= self.damage
                            print(str(self.damage) + " damage")
                            self.moves_left = self.moves_left - 1
            else:
                return 


class Goblin(Character):
    def __init__(self):
        Character.__init__(self, "Goblin", random.randint(15,20), random.randint(0,MAPSIZE-1), random.randint(0,MAPSIZE-1), 10, random.randint(0,1))

    def random_move(self):
        i = random.randint(0,3)
        if i == 0:
            self.move("N")
        elif i == 1:
            self.move("S")
        elif i == 2:
            self.move("W")
        elif i == 3:
            self.move("E")

        self.moves_left = 10


class Archer(Character):
    def __init__(self):
        Character.__init__(self, "Archer", random.randint(15,20), random.randint(0,MAPSIZE-1), random.randint(0,MAPSIZE-1))


class Warrior(Character):
    def __init__(self):
        Character.__init__(self, "Warrior", random.randint(15,20), random.randint(0,MAPSIZE-1), random.randint(0,MAPSIZE-1))


class Scout(Character):
    def __init__(self):
        Character.__init__(self, "Scout", random.randint(15,20), random.randint(0,MAPSIZE-1), random.randint(0,MAPSIZE-1))


class Rogue(Character):
    def __init__(self):
        Character.__init__(self, "Rogue", random.randint(15,20), random.randint(0,MAPSIZE-1), random.randint(0,MAPSIZE-1))


class Wizard(Character):
    def __init__(self):
        Character.__init__(self, "Wizard", random.randint(15,20), random.randint(0,MAPSIZE-1), random.randint(0,MAPSIZE-1))


class Map(object):              #The main class; where the action happens
    global MAPSIZE
    wild_characters = []
    can_move = []
    no_moves = []
    Grid = []
    friendlies = []
    enemies = []
    everyone = [friendlies + enemies]
    visible = []

    for row in range(MAPSIZE):     # Creating grid
        Grid.append([])
        for column in range(MAPSIZE):
            Grid[row].append([])

    for row in range(MAPSIZE):     #Filling grid with grass
        for column in range(MAPSIZE):
            TempTile = MapTile("Grass", column, row, False)
            Grid[column][row].append(TempTile)

    for row in range(MAPSIZE):     #Putting some rocks near the top
        for column in range(MAPSIZE):
            TempTile = MapTile("Rock", column, row, False)
            if row == 1:
                Grid[column][row].append(TempTile)

    for i in range(10):         #Trees in random places
        random_row = random.randint(0, MAPSIZE - 1)
        random_column = random.randint(0, MAPSIZE - 1)
        TempTile = MapTile("Tree", random_column, random_row, False)
        Grid[random_column][random_row].append(TempTile)

    def generate_hero(self):            #Generate a character and place it randomly
        temp_hero = Character("Hero", 30, random.randint(0, MAPSIZE - 1), random.randint(0, MAPSIZE - 1) , 10, random.randint(0,1))
        self.Grid[temp_hero.internal_column][temp_hero.internal_row].append(temp_hero)
        self.can_move.append(temp_hero)
        if temp_hero.allegiance == 0:
            self.friendlies.append(temp_hero)
        elif temp_hero.allegiance == 1:
            self.enemies.append(temp_hero)

    def return_distance(self, pointA, pointB):
        distance = math.sqrt((pointA.internal_column - pointB.internal_column)**2 + (pointA.internal_row - pointB.internal_row)**2)
        return distance

    def generate_goblin(self):            #Generate a character and place it randomly
        random_row = random.randint(0, MAPSIZE - 1)
        random_column = random.randint(0, MAPSIZE - 1)
        temp_goblin = Goblin()
        self.Grid[random_column][random_row].append(temp_goblin)
        Map.wild_characters.append(temp_goblin)

    def update(self):           
        for column in range(MAPSIZE):                           #These nested loops go through entire grid 
            for row in range(MAPSIZE):                          #They check if any objects internal coordinates
                for i in range(len(Map.Grid[column][row])):     #disagree with its place on the grid and update it accordingly                            
                    if Map.Grid[column][row][i].internal_column != column:
                        TempChar = Map.Grid[column][row][i]
                        Map.Grid[column][row].remove(Map.Grid[column][row][i])
                        Map.Grid[int(TempChar.internal_column)][int(TempChar.internal_row)].append(TempChar)

                    elif Map.Grid[column][row][i].internal_row != row:
                        TempChar = Map.Grid[column][row][i]
                        Map.Grid[column][row].remove(Map.Grid[column][row][i])
                        Map.Grid[int(TempChar.internal_column)][int(TempChar.internal_row)].append(TempChar)

        temparr = Map.no_moves[:]
        for characterobject in temparr:    #This moves any characters with moves to the can move list 
            if len(temparr) > 0:
                if characterobject.moves_left > 0:
                    Map.can_move.append(characterobject)
                    Map.no_moves.remove(characterobject)
            if characterobject.HP <= 0:
                Map.no_moves.remove(characterobject)

        arr = Map.can_move[:] # copy
        for item in arr:
            if item.moves_left == 0:
                Map.can_move.remove(item)
                Map.no_moves.append(item)
            if item.HP <= 0:
                Map.can_move.remove(item)

        for column in range(MAPSIZE):                           
            for row in range(MAPSIZE):                          
                for i in range(len(Map.Grid[column][row])):     
                    if Map.Grid[column][row][i].__class__.__name__ == "Character":
                        if Map.Grid[column][row][i].HP <= 0:
                            Map.Grid[column][row].remove(Map.Grid[column][row][i])
                            print("Character died")

        for column in range(MAPSIZE):
            for row in range(MAPSIZE):
                for i in range(len(Map.Grid[column][row])):
                    if Map.Grid[column][row][i].__class__.__name__ == "Character":
                        Map.everyone.append(Map.Grid[column][row][i])

        for character in Map.everyone:            
            for column in range(MAPSIZE):
                for row in range(MAPSIZE):
                    if Map.return_distance(Map.Grid[column][row][0], character ) <= 15:
                        Map.Grid[column][row].visible = True

    def listofcharacters(self):
        for column in range(MAPSIZE):
            for row in range(MAPSIZE):
                for i in range(len(Map.Grid[column][row])):
                    if Map.Grid[column][row][i].__class__.__name__ == "Character":
                        print("Column: ", Map.Grid[column][row][i].internal_column, ", Row: ", Map.Grid[column][row][i].internal_row, ", Allegiance: ", Map.Grid[column][row][i].allegiance)





Map = Map()
Map.generate_hero()

while not DONE:     #Main pygame loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():         #catching events
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            DONE = True       
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            Pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            column = Pos[0] // (TILEWIDTH + TILEMARGIN)  #Translating the position of the mouse into rows and columns
            row = Pos[1] // (TILEHEIGHT + TILEMARGIN)
            print(str(row) + ", " + str(column))

            for i in range(len(Map.Grid[column][row])):
                print(str(Map.Grid[column][row][i].name))  #print stuff that inhabits that square

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            wild_char_arr = Map.wild_characters[:]

            for wildcharacter in wild_char_arr:
                if wildcharacter.name == "Goblin":
                    wildcharacter.random_move() 

            if event.key == 97:      # Keypress: a
                print("New turn.")
                temparr = Map.no_moves[:]
                for item in temparr:
                    if item.moves_left == 0:
                        item.moves_left = 15
                TURN = TURN + 1
                print("Turn: ", TURN)

            elif event.key == 115:    # Keypress: s
                print("Generated hero.")
                Map.generate_hero()

            elif event.key == 113:    # Keypress: q     
                print("ranged attack")
                Map.can_move[0].ranged_attack(Map.can_move[0].direction)

            elif event.key == 119:    # Keypress: w
                print("Generated hero.")
                Map.generate_hero()

            elif event.key == 101:    # Keypress: e
                print("Generated hero.")
                Map.generate_hero()

            elif event.key == 114:    # Keypress: r
                print("Generated hero.")
                Map.generate_hero()

            elif event.key == 116:    # Keypress: t
                print("Generated hero.")
                Map.generate_hero()

            elif event.key == 100:  # Keypress: d
                Map.generate_goblin()
                print("Generated goblin.")

            elif event.key == 102:  # Keypress: f
                Map.can_move[0].attack(Map.can_move[0].direction) 

            elif len(Map.can_move) > 0:
                Map.can_move[0].move(KeyLookup[event.key])

            else:
                print("invalid")

            Map.update()

    Screen.fill(BLACK)

    for row in range(MAPSIZE):           # Drawing grid
        for column in range(MAPSIZE):
            for i in range(0, len(Map.Grid[column][row])):
                Color = WHITE

                if len(Map.can_move) > 0:   # Creating colored area around character showing his move range
                    if (math.sqrt((Map.can_move[0].internal_column - column)**2 + (Map.can_move[0].internal_row - row)**2)) <= Map.can_move[0].moves_left:
                        Color = MOVECOLOR

                if len(Map.Grid[column][row]) > 1:
                    Color = RED
                if Map.Grid[column][row][i].name == "Tree":

                    Color = GREEN
                if str(Map.Grid[column][row][i].__class__.__name__) == "Character":
                    Color = BROWN

            pygame.draw.rect(Screen, Color, [(TILEMARGIN + TILEWIDTH) * column + TILEMARGIN,
                                             (TILEMARGIN + TILEHEIGHT) * row + TILEMARGIN,
                                             TILEWIDTH,
                                             TILEHEIGHT])

            if str(Map.Grid[column][row][i].__class__.__name__) == "Character":
                if Map.Grid[column][row][i].direction == "N":
                    Color = RED

                    pygame.draw.rect(Screen, Color, [(TILEMARGIN + TILEWIDTH) * column + TILEMARGIN + 8,
                                             (TILEMARGIN + TILEHEIGHT) * row + TILEMARGIN,
                                             TILEWIDTH/4,
                                             TILEHEIGHT/4])

            if str(Map.Grid[column][row][i].__class__.__name__) == "Character":
                if Map.Grid[column][row][i].direction == "S":
                    Color = RED

                    pygame.draw.rect(Screen, Color, [(TILEMARGIN + TILEWIDTH) * column + TILEMARGIN + 8,
                                             (TILEMARGIN + TILEHEIGHT) * row + TILEMARGIN*5 - 1 ,
                                             TILEWIDTH/4,
                                             TILEHEIGHT/4])

            if str(Map.Grid[column][row][i].__class__.__name__) == "Character":
                if Map.Grid[column][row][i].direction == "E":
                    Color = RED

                    pygame.draw.rect(Screen, Color, [(TILEMARGIN + TILEWIDTH) * column + TILEMARGIN + 15,
                                             (TILEMARGIN + TILEHEIGHT) * row + TILEMARGIN*5 - 8,
                                             TILEWIDTH/4,
                                             TILEHEIGHT/4])

            if str(Map.Grid[column][row][i].__class__.__name__) == "Character":
                if Map.Grid[column][row][i].direction == "W":
                    Color = RED

                    pygame.draw.rect(Screen, Color, [(TILEMARGIN + TILEWIDTH) * column + TILEMARGIN
                                                     ,
                                             (TILEMARGIN + TILEHEIGHT) * row + TILEMARGIN*5 - 8 ,
                                             TILEWIDTH/4,
                                             TILEHEIGHT/4])


    Clock.tick(60)      
    pygame.display.flip()     

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more info on what the types of each member are expected to be.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Well one of Map.Grid[column][row] or character is a list instead of a MapTile. What type of object were you expecting to occupy each of those expressions?

Comment: Map.Grid[column][row] is supposed to be a MapTile object, and character is supposed to be a Character object. Both have internal_row and internal_column characteristics. Map.everyone is supposed to have only Character objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Map`:

```
friendlies = []
enemies = []
everyone = [friendlies + enemies]
```

This means `everyone` is defined as as a list of an empty list:  `[ [] + [] ]` == `[ [] ]`.  This in turn means:

```
for character in Map.everyone:
```

`character` is the empty list `[]`, which causes your error.

Also, because this is evaluated once at the time of the assignment, when you later modify `friendlies` and `enemies` it does not change the value of `everyone`.

Comment: How do I make it so that everyone is truly just the combined contents of friendlies and enemies? So that when either updates, everyone will be the contents of it instead an empty list + the contents? To update as friendlies and enemies update?

Comment: There's no built-in way that I know of to automatically composite two lists into a third and have updates to the source lists be reflected in the composite list.  this should be asked as a separate question. :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are creating a list of lists of lists, when you just need a list of lists. The `row` list can contain your `MapTile`s directly; no need to fill it with more lists.

Try this instead:

```
for row in range(MAPSIZE):     # Creating grid
    Grid.append([])

for row in range(MAPSIZE):     #Filling grid with grass
    for column in range(MAPSIZE):
        TempTile = MapTile("Grass", column, row, False)
        Grid[row].append(TempTile)
```

This way, Grid is just a list of rows, and each row is a list of tiles, one tile per column.